# Wordpress URL & Site URL as subdir /~new/ but it is in fact in public_html?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I am finishing someone else's work on a Wordpress installation and this makes me confused - in wp_options WP URL and Site URL are both http://example.com/~new/. With http://example.com/ you'll just get the message that Apache is functioning normally. But in FTP the WP installation is in fact in public_html and if I get a path to root (echo getcwd();) with a script located in subdir adminer in the directory that has the WP installation I do get the structure without /~new/

/home/site/domains/apps/public_html/adminer

What is this? A phony directory?

(The trouble is I obviously need to show the landing page (currently only with /~new/) on the domain)

Comment: You should start reading documentations. The `~` character is typically interpreted as "the users home directory". Look if there is some plugin (module) loaded into your http server doing that. Maybe start reading here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_userdir.html

Comment: Oh. A user subdir. Cheers.